# Issue creating .csv file with multiple lines using ansible playbook - dict object has no attribute stdout_lines

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml, redhat

I'm trying to create a .csv file that lists the Linux hostname and users on that server on separate lines.  So I'd like it to look like this:

```
Hostname  User
server1   bill
server1   bonnie
server2   jim
server2   jack
```

I'm getting stuck on creating new lines for each user and it's just creating one long line.  Should I be using loop or with_items?  I'm getting the same {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'"} error with each.

Here's my playbook and I believe the last line is where my issue is at:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - name: Create empty /tmp/rhel_user_list.csv file
    shell:  echo 'Hostname, User List' > {{report_path}}
    args:
      chdir: /tmp
    run_once: true

  - name: Get user list
    getent:
      database: passwd
    register: user_list

  - debug:
      var: user_list

  - name: Show gathered local user names only
    debug:
      msg: "{{ user_list.results | json_query('[].ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys(@)') }}"

  - name: Write username only to file
    lineinfile:
      line: "{{ansible_hostname}}, {{ getent_passwd.keys() | list }}"
      path: "{{report_path}}"
    with_items: "{{ user_list.stdout_lines }}"
```

I've tried using loop and with_items to no avail.  I'm getting the same dict object has no attribute, but I'm not sure which attribute to use.

Comment: Which host would you like to write the file to?

Comment: localhost is fine.  I just need to be able to export it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

For example, the play below writes the aggregate of all hosts and users to the controller

```yaml
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - getent:
        database: passwd

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/user_list.csv
        content: |
          Hostname User
          {% for h in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {% for u in hostvars[h].getent_passwd %}
          {{ h }} {{ u }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

---

Notes:

- The module *getent* creates [*getent_<database>*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/getent_module.html#returned-facts) in *hostvars* automatically
- See [*hostvars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)
- See [*Delegating tasks*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks)
- See *ansible_play_hosts* in [*Special Variables*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)
- It might be useful to write a YAML dictionary to a file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/user_dict.yml
        content: |
          {% for h in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {{ {h: hostvars[h].getent_passwd.keys()|list}|to_yaml }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

- This can be easily used later. For example,

```yaml
    - block:
        - include_vars:
            file: /tmp/user_dict.yml
            name: user_dict
        - debug:
            var: user_dict|to_yaml
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [server1] => 
  user_dict|to_yaml: |-
    server1: [root, toor, daemon, operator, bin, tty, kmem, games, news, man, sshd, smmsp,
      mailnull, bind, unbound, proxy, _pflogd, _dhcp, uucp, pop, auditdistd, www, ntpd,
      _ypldap, hast, tests, nobody, admin, User1, MyUser1, alice, bob]
    server2: [root, toor, daemon, operator, bin, tty, kmem, games, news, man, sshd, smmsp,
      mailnull, bind, unbound, proxy, _pflogd, _dhcp, uucp, pop, auditdistd, www, ntpd,
      _ypldap, hast, tests, nobody, admin]
```